# KDE Weather widget issues

Tags: plasma

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 wily with KDE plasma 5.4.1 and it works fine except I can't seem to get the weather plasma widget to work. I have installed it using synaptic package manager from ubuntu's repository but I get a very long message string pasted below when I try to open/run the widget on the menu bar:
"Error loading QML file: file:///home/philip/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.weatherWidget/contents/ui/main.qml:114:5: Type OpenWeatherMap unavailable
file:///home/philip/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.weatherWidget/contents/ui/providers/OpenWeatherMap.qml:18:1: module "QtQuick.XmlListModel" is not installed".
does anyone have any idea how to get this widget to work?? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, I installed "qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel" and rebooted and this solved it!